# How do i select records of crystal subreports dynamically

Tags: crystal-reports

Good people of stack overflow.

I am stuck on this one.my crystal report is using a joined query

```
       str = "SELECT invoices.voucher, 
              invoices.customer_name,invoice_details.item_name,
              invoice_details.Amount FROM   invoices  
              LEFT OUTER JOIN invoice_details  
              ON invoices.voucher =invoice_details.voucher "
```

The crystal report is grouped by voucher and the details are placed on detail section of group details to display item name and item amount.
It is working perfectly in design.

However at run time in VBNET when i select exactly the same query i get repeating line items. Example if the invoice items in invoice_details table were three in my report the three items will be repeated three times.

I have checked all over the internet for the same complain. No luck.
Someone suggested "suppress if duplicate" on an item with unique number such as voucher number. I did not get success.

Has someone met this difficulty and can you suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: looks like left outer join is the culprit here... try using inner join also fire the same query on database and check records

Comment: Thanks siva. unfortunately still duplicating.

Answer (score 0):

If it can be of help to someone else...
My difficulty in duplicating line items was coming from using two tables, invoices and invoice_details when designing the crystal report.

And then using the link feature at crystal report design.

I had not realized i ought to have designed crystal report using a stored view (access query from the database). While using the stored view i did not do any linking at designing report but used grouping expert to group by invoice numbers.

So the report finally worked well after much frustration.